# multi_format with multiple lines (logs)

Tags: fluentd

Yoo!
I'm new to fluentd and I've been messing around with it to work with GKE, and stepped upon one issue.

### Problem

I'm using a filter to parse the containers log and I need different regex expressions so I added [multi_format](https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser) and it worked perfectly. After that I noticed that Tracelogs and exceptions were being splited into different logs/lines, so I then saw the [multiline](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/multiline) parser but didn't go as planned (it didn't work). I then found out why in the [README.md of the multi-format repo](https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-multi-format-parser/blob/master/README.md#note)

> #### NOTE
>
> This plugin doesn't work with `multiline` parsers because parser itself doesn't store previous lines.

### Question

So I was wondering if somehow it was possible to workaround this limitation and have multiple regexes to filter the logs and also have a multi line parser or concat

### Config file

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  #[[START configMapNameCM]]
  name: fluentd-gcp-config-custom
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-gcp-custom
#[[END configMapNameCM]]
data:
  containers.input.conf: |-
    # This configuration file for Fluentd is used
    # to watch changes to Docker log files that live in the
    # directory /var/lib/docker/containers/ and are symbolically
    # linked to from the /var/log/containers directory using names that capture the
    # pod name and container name. These logs are then submitted to
    # Google Cloud Logging which assumes the installation of the cloud-logging plug-in.
    #
    # Example
    # =======
    # A line in the Docker log file might look like this JSON:
    #
    # {"log":"2014/09/25 21:15:03 Got request with path wombat\\n",
    #  "stream":"stderr",
    #   "time":"2014-09-25T21:15:03.499185026Z"}
    #
    # The original tag is derived from the log file's location.
    # For example a Docker container's logs might be in the directory:
    #  /var/lib/docker/containers/997599971ee6366d4a5920d25b79286ad45ff37a74494f262e3bc98d909d0a7b
    # and in the file:
    #  997599971ee6366d4a5920d25b79286ad45ff37a74494f262e3bc98d909d0a7b-json.log
    # where 997599971ee6... is the Docker ID of the running container.
    # The Kubernetes kubelet makes a symbolic link to this file on the host
    # machine in the /var/log/containers directory which includes the pod name,
    # the namespace name and the Kubernetes container name:
    #    synthetic-logger-0.25lps-pod_default_synth-lgr-997599971ee6366d4a5920d25b79286ad45ff37a74494f262e3bc98d909d0a7b.log
    #    ->
    #    /var/lib/docker/containers/997599971ee6366d4a5920d25b79286ad45ff37a74494f262e3bc98d909d0a7b/997599971ee6366d4a5920d25b79286ad45ff37a74494f262e3bc98d909d0a7b-json.log
    # The /var/log directory on the host is mapped to the /var/log directory in the container
    # running this instance of Fluentd and we end up collecting the file:
    #   /var/log/containers/synthetic-logger-0.25lps-pod_default_synth-lgr-997599971ee6366d4a5920d25b79286ad45ff37a74494f262e3bc98d909d0a7b.log
    # This results in the tag:
    #  var.log.containers.synthetic-logger-0.25lps-pod_default_synth-lgr-997599971ee6366d4a5920d25b79286ad45ff37a74494f262e3bc98d909d0a7b.log
    # where 'synthetic-logger-0.25lps-pod' is the pod name, 'default' is the
    # namespace name, 'synth-lgr' is the container name and '997599971ee6..' is
    # the container ID.
    # The record reformer is used to extract pod_name, namespace_name and
    # container_name from the tag and set them in a local_resource_id in the
    # format of:
    # 'k8s_container.<NAMESPACE_NAME>.<POD_NAME>.<CONTAINER_NAME>'.
    # The reformer also changes the tags to 'stderr' or 'stdout' based on the
    # value of 'stream'.
    # local_resource_id is later used by google_cloud plugin to determine the
    # monitored resource to ingest logs against.

    # Json Log Example:
    # {"log":"[info:2016-02-16T16:04:05.930-08:00] Some log text here\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2016-02-17T00:04:05.931087621Z"}
    # CRI Log Example:
    # 2016-02-17T00:04:05.931087621Z stdout F [info:2016-02-16T16:04:05.930-08:00] Some log text here
    <source>
      @type tail
      path /var/log/containers/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-containers.log.pos
      # Tags at this point are in the format of:
      # reform.var.log.containers.<POD_NAME>_<NAMESPACE_NAME>_<CONTAINER_NAME>-<CONTAINER_ID>.log
      tag reform.*
      read_from_head true
      <parse>
        @type multi_format
        <pattern>
          format json
          time_key time
          time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          format /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$/
          time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z
        </pattern>
      </parse>
    </source>

    <filter reform.var.log.containers.backend*.log>
      @type parser
      key_name log
      <parse>
        @type multi_format
        <pattern>
          # Gunicorn logs
          format regexp
          expression /^\[(?<time>[\d -:,+ZT\.]+)\] \[(?<pid>\d+)\] \[(?<severity>[a-zA-Z]+)\] (?<log>.+)$/
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          # Backend logging
          format regexp
          expression /^(?<time>[\d -:,+ZT\.]+) - (?<severity>[a-zA-Z]+) - (?<log>.+)$/
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          # Alembic logs
          format regexp
          expression /^(?<severity>[a-zA-Z]+)[ \t\x0B\f\r]+\[(?<name>.+)\] (?<log>.+)$/
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          # Access logs
          format regexp
          expression /^(?<target>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5}) - (?<log>.+)$/
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
          format none
        </pattern>
      </parse>
      reserve_data true
      emit_invalid_record_to_error false
    </filter>

    <filter reform.var.log.containers.listener*.log>
      @type parser
      key_name log
      format /^(?<time>[\d -:,+ZT\.]+) - (?<name>.+) - (?<severity>[a-zA-Z]+) - (?<log>.+)$/
      reserve_data true
      emit_invalid_record_to_error false
    </filter>

    <match reform.**>
      @type record_reformer
      enable_ruby true
      <record>
        # Extract local_resource_id from tag for 'k8s_container' monitored
        # resource. The format is:
        # 'k8s_container.<namespace_name>.<pod_name>.<container_name>'.
        "logging.googleapis.com/local_resource_id" ${"k8s_container.#{tag_suffix[4].rpartition('.')[0].split('_')[1]}.#{tag_suffix[4].rpartition('.')[0].split('_')[0]}.#{tag_suffix[4].rpartition('.')[0].split('_')[2].rpartition('-')[0]}"}
        # Rename the field 'log' to a more generic field 'message'. This way the
        # fluent-plugin-google-cloud knows to flatten the field as textPayload
        # instead of jsonPayload after extracting 'time', 'severity' and
        # 'stream' from the record.
        message ${record['log']}
        # If 'severity' is not set, assume stderr is ERROR and stdout is INFO.
        severity ${record['severity'] || if record['stream'] == 'stderr' then 'ERROR' else 'INFO' end}
      </record>
      tag ${if record['stream'] == 'stderr' then 'raw.stderr' else 'raw.stdout' end}
      remove_keys stream,log
    </match>

    # Detect exceptions in the log output and forward them as one log entry.
    <match {raw.stderr,raw.stdout}>
      @type detect_exceptions

      remove_tag_prefix raw
      message message
      stream "logging.googleapis.com/local_resource_id"
      multiline_flush_interval 5
      max_bytes 500000
      max_lines 1000
    </match>
  monitoring.conf: |-
    # This source is used to acquire approximate process start timestamp,
    # which purpose is explained before the corresponding output plugin.
    <source>
      @type exec
      command /bin/sh -c 'date +%s'
      tag process_start
      time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
      keys process_start_timestamp
    </source>

    # This filter is used to convert process start timestamp to integer
    # value for correct ingestion in the prometheus output plugin.
    <filter process_start>
      @type record_transformer
      enable_ruby true
      auto_typecast true
      <record>
        process_start_timestamp ${record["process_start_timestamp"].to_i}
      </record>
    </filter>
  system.input.conf: |-
    # Example:
    # Dec 21 23:17:22 gke-foo-1-1-4b5cbd14-node-4eoj startupscript: Finished running startup script /var/run/google.startup.script
    <source>
      @type tail
      format syslog
      path /var/log/startupscript.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-startupscript.log.pos
      tag startupscript
    </source>

    # Examples:
    # time="2016-02-04T06:51:03.053580605Z" level=info msg="GET /containers/json"
    # time="2016-02-04T07:53:57.505612354Z" level=error msg="HTTP Error" err="No such image: -f" statusCode=404
    # TODO(random-liu): Remove this after cri container runtime rolls out.
    <source>
      @type tail
      format /^time="(?<time>[^)]*)" level=(?<severity>[^ ]*) msg="(?<message>[^"]*)"( err="(?<error>[^"]*)")?( statusCode=($<status_code>\d+))?/
      path /var/log/docker.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-docker.log.pos
      tag docker
    </source>

    # Example:
    # 2016/02/04 06:52:38 filePurge: successfully removed file /var/etcd/data/member/wal/00000000000006d0-00000000010a23d1.wal
    <source>
      @type tail
      # Not parsing this, because it doesn't have anything particularly useful to
      # parse out of it (like severities).
      format none
      path /var/log/etcd.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-etcd.log.pos
      tag etcd
    </source>

    # Multi-line parsing is required for all the kube logs because very large log
    # statements, such as those that include entire object bodies, get split into
    # multiple lines by glog.

    # Example:
    # I0204 07:32:30.020537    3368 server.go:1048] POST /stats/container/: (13.972191ms) 200 [[Go-http-client/1.1] 10.244.1.3:40537]
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/kubelet.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-kubelet.log.pos
      tag kubelet
    </source>

    # Example:
    # I1118 21:26:53.975789       6 proxier.go:1096] Port "nodePort for kube-system/default-http-backend:http" (:31429/tcp) was open before and is still needed
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/kube-proxy.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-kube-proxy.log.pos
      tag kube-proxy
    </source>

    # Example:
    # I0204 07:00:19.604280       5 handlers.go:131] GET /api/v1/nodes: (1.624207ms) 200 [[kube-controller-manager/v1.1.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/6a81b50] 127.0.0.1:38266]
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/kube-apiserver.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-kube-apiserver.log.pos
      tag kube-apiserver
    </source>

    # Example:
    # I0204 06:55:31.872680       5 servicecontroller.go:277] LB already exists and doesn't need update for service kube-system/kube-ui
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/kube-controller-manager.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-kube-controller-manager.log.pos
      tag kube-controller-manager
    </source>

    # Example:
    # W0204 06:49:18.239674       7 reflector.go:245] pkg/scheduler/factory/factory.go:193: watch of *api.Service ended with: 401: The event in requested index is outdated and cleared (the requested history has been cleared [2578313/2577886]) [2579312]
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/kube-scheduler.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-kube-scheduler.log.pos
      tag kube-scheduler
    </source>

    # Example:
    # I1104 10:36:20.242766       5 rescheduler.go:73] Running Rescheduler
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/rescheduler.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-rescheduler.log.pos
      tag rescheduler
    </source>

    # Example:
    # I0603 15:31:05.793605       6 cluster_manager.go:230] Reading config from path /etc/gce.conf
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/glbc.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-glbc.log.pos
      tag glbc
    </source>

    # Example:
    # I0603 15:31:05.793605       6 cluster_manager.go:230] Reading config from path /etc/gce.conf
    <source>
      @type tail
      format multiline
      multiline_flush_interval 5s
      format_firstline /^\w\d{4}/
      format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
      time_format %m%d %H:%M:%S.%N
      path /var/log/cluster-autoscaler.log
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-cluster-autoscaler.log.pos
      tag cluster-autoscaler
    </source>

    # Logs from systemd-journal for interesting services.
    # TODO(random-liu): Keep this for compatibility, remove this after
    # cri container runtime rolls out.
    <source>
      @type systemd
      filters [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "docker.service" }]
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-journald-docker.pos
      read_from_head true
      tag docker
    </source>

    <source>
      @type systemd
      filters [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "{{ fluentd_container_runtime_service }}.service" }]
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-journald-container-runtime.pos
      read_from_head true
      tag container-runtime
    </source>

    <source>
      @type systemd
      filters [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "kubelet.service" }]
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-journald-kubelet.pos
      read_from_head true
      tag kubelet
    </source>

    <source>
      @type systemd
      filters [{ "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "node-problem-detector.service" }]
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-journald-node-problem-detector.pos
      read_from_head true
      tag node-problem-detector
    </source>

    # BEGIN_NODE_JOURNAL
    # Whether to include node-journal or not is determined when starting the
    # cluster. It is not changed when the cluster is already running.
    <source>
      @type systemd
      pos_file /var/log/gcp-journald.pos
      read_from_head true
      tag node-journal
    </source>

    <filter node-journal>
      @type grep
      <exclude>
        key _SYSTEMD_UNIT
        pattern ^(docker|{{ fluentd_container_runtime_service }}|kubelet|node-problem-detector)\.service$
      </exclude>
    </filter>
    # END_NODE_JOURNAL
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd-gcp-main-config
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-gcp-custom
data:
  google-fluentd.conf: |-
    @include config.d/*.conf
    # This match is placed before the all-matching output to provide metric
    # exporter with a process start timestamp for correct exporting of
    # cumulative metrics to Stackdriver.
    <match process_start>
      @type prometheus

      <metric>
        type gauge
        name process_start_time_seconds
        desc Timestamp of the process start in seconds
        key process_start_timestamp
      </metric>
    </match>

    # This filter allows to count the number of log entries read by fluentd
    # before they are processed by the output plugin. This in turn allows to
    # monitor the number of log entries that were read but never sent, e.g.
    # because of liveness probe removing buffer.
    <filter **>
      @type prometheus
      <metric>
        type counter
        name logging_entry_count
        desc Total number of log entries generated by either application containers or system components
      </metric>
    </filter>

    # This section is exclusive for k8s_container logs. Those come with
    # 'stderr'/'stdout' tags.
    # TODO(instrumentation): Reconsider this workaround later.
    # Trim the entries which exceed slightly less than 256KB, to avoid
    # dropping them. It is a necessity, because Stackdriver only supports
    # entries that are up to 256KB in size.
    <filter {stderr,stdout}>
      @type record_transformer
      enable_ruby true
      <record>
        message ${record['message'].length > 256000 ? "[Trimmed]#{record['message'][0..256000]}..." : record['message']}
      </record>
    </filter>

    # Do not collect fluentd's own logs to avoid infinite loops.
    <match fluent.**>
      @type null
    </match>

    # Add a unique insertId to each log entry that doesn't already have it.
    # This helps guarantee the order and prevent log duplication.
    <filter **>
      @type add_insert_ids
    </filter>

    # This section is exclusive for k8s_container logs. These logs come with
    # 'stderr'/'stdout' tags.
    # We use a separate output stanza for 'k8s_node' logs with a smaller buffer
    # because node logs are less important than user's container logs.
    <match {stderr,stdout}>
      @type google_cloud

      # Try to detect JSON formatted log entries.
      detect_json true
      # Collect metrics in Prometheus registry about plugin activity.
      enable_monitoring true
      monitoring_type prometheus
      # Allow log entries from multiple containers to be sent in the same request.
      split_logs_by_tag false
      # Set the buffer type to file to improve the reliability and reduce the memory consumption
      buffer_type file
      buffer_path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes.containers.buffer
      # Set queue_full action to block because we want to pause gracefully
      # in case of the off-the-limits load instead of throwing an exception
      buffer_queue_full_action block
      # Set the chunk limit conservatively to avoid exceeding the recommended
      # chunk size of 5MB per write request.
      buffer_chunk_limit 512k
      # Cap the combined memory usage of this buffer and the one below to
      # 512KiB/chunk * (6 + 2) chunks = 4 MiB
      buffer_queue_limit 6
      # Never wait more than 5 seconds before flushing logs in the non-error case.
      flush_interval 5s
      # Never wait longer than 30 seconds between retries.
      max_retry_wait 30
      # Disable the limit on the number of retries (retry forever).
      disable_retry_limit
      # Use multiple threads for processing.
      num_threads 2
      use_grpc true
      # Skip timestamp adjustment as this is in a controlled environment with
      # known timestamp format. This helps with CPU usage.
      adjust_invalid_timestamps false
    </match>

    # Attach local_resource_id for 'k8s_node' monitored resource.
    <filter **>
      @type record_transformer
      enable_ruby true
      <record>
        "logging.googleapis.com/local_resource_id" ${"k8s_node.#{ENV['NODE_NAME']}"}
      </record>
    </filter>

    # This section is exclusive for 'k8s_node' logs. These logs come with tags
    # that are neither 'stderr' or 'stdout'.
    # We use a separate output stanza for 'k8s_container' logs with a larger
    # buffer because user's container logs are more important than node logs.
    <match **>
      @type google_cloud

      detect_json true
      enable_monitoring true
      monitoring_type prometheus
      # Allow entries from multiple system logs to be sent in the same request.
      split_logs_by_tag false
      detect_subservice false
      buffer_type file
      buffer_path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/kubernetes.system.buffer
      buffer_queue_full_action block
      buffer_chunk_limit 512k
      buffer_queue_limit 2
      flush_interval 5s
      max_retry_wait 30
      disable_retry_limit
      num_threads 2
      use_grpc true
      # Skip timestamp adjustment as this is in a controlled environment with
      # known timestamp format. This helps with CPU usage.
      adjust_invalid_timestamps false
    </match>
```